# Can I have a Function in the THEN clause of a SQL Select statement?

Tags: sql, case

Can I have a Function in the THEN clause of a SQL Select statement?  e.g.

```
CASE 
WHEN Title = 'Chief Operating Officer'
    THEN [GetManager](EmployeeNumber)
WHEN Title = 'Partner' 
    THEN NULL
ELSE [GetManager](EmployeeNumber)
END as ManagerName,
```

Comment: You could give it a try and see what happens? Experience through trying it is always worthwhile.

Comment: Bet you can. Add a tag with your database system.

Answer (score 0):

In case statement expression can be function, constant, column name, subquery, inbuilt functions like ISNULL, NULLIF etc.

So to answer your question, yes you can use a function in the then clause of SQL Select statement.

Comment: Careful with table-valued functions.